# How to use multi-customized UITableCell in just one UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell, customization

I am developing an iphone application which have a complicated view is to display stocks information with 3 sections:
- Extended quote which include a chart and stock info (id, price...)
- Other quote info
- News (headline)

They are should be grouped and user can click on its header to expand or collapse the content.

As I know I should use UITableView with customized cells, but I just find out the way to custom all cells in a same way, but here, I need at least 3 different types.

Does anybody have experience about this please tell me what should I do?

Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in StackOverflow and in the internet, finally, I found the way to show multi-customized UITableCell in just one UITableView by checking the row index / section which you want to custom, create a new UIView then add it into cell content view, also, we can use this way to custom the section header and UITable header.